# Custom post with div too much margin

Tags: css, wordpress

i'm having a slight problem which i can't seem to figure out how to solve in a wordpress layout.

I have 3 columns which shows the recent posts with each one being an individual  by itself, but as the div increases in height, it pushes the next line of div downwards, but what i wanted is just each div having a 20 px margin with each other.

**here's a picture of what is happening**[image]

**here's a picture of what i want**[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to implement the layout you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS alone will not get you the effect that you are looking for. For the full effect, and a well put together tutorial, visit:

http://benholland.me/javascript/how-to-build-a-site-that-works-like-pinterest/